# How to check for double quotes in a string object

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to create a method called `contains_double_quotes(argument)?`, which checks whether the string `argument` contains quotes. In other words, it should return

- `true` if `argument` is `"\"which one is your favorite\""`.
- `false` if `argument` is `"hello"` or `"this is a regular string value"`.

I attempted this as below, but am not sure if this is the best way to do this. What could be some problems with this sort of logic?

```
def contains_double_quotes(argument)
  argument.include?("\"")
end
```

Once I get `true` from this call, I'd like to remove the double quotes from `argument` so I can use it as a normal string value. How can I remove the double quotes from this?

Comment: If you want to remove all double quotes from the string `str` (that is, modify `str`), you can use `str.delete! ?"`. That will remove all double quotes, and as part of the bargain, will return the resulting string (which is "truthy") if any were present (and removed), or `nil` if the string contained no double quotes.

Comment: @Cary I'm against programming idioms that allow specific and narrow conveniences like you mentioned because they violate common denominators amongst many other languages. God forbid if I use ruby for too long without using Java.

Comment: It's easy enough to turn it into a method that is as general as you like.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that, when it has double quotes, then they appear at the beginning and the end of the string only. Is that the case? If so, you should make that clear in the question.

Comment: Do you mean a string object, not a string literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all double quotes with empty strings:

```
string.tr "\"", ""
```

Comment: or `string.tr '"', ''`

Comment: Yup, beat me to it :)

Comment: yea, but is my `include?` check accurate? Removing them is my second concern, but first i must detect them properly, and carry out a certain operation.

Comment: Yes, the include? check should work fine as well. But if you use this method, you won't remove any characters that are not double quotes because it explicitly searches for double quotes only.

Comment: I understand that it only searches for it. If found it will do something and only then later in the code it will remove using your solution. thanks

Answer (score 2):

A benchmark might be useful:

```
require 'fruity'

str = '"' + ('a'..'z').to_a.join * 10 + '"'
compare {
  _delete { str.delete('"') }
  _gsub   { str.gsub('"', '') }
  _tr     { str.tr('"', '') }
}

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _gsub is faster than _delete by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> _delete is faster than _tr by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
```

---

> Could you add delete!

Here's a comparison of the respective `!` versions:

```
require 'fruity'

str = '"' + ('a'..'z').to_a.join * 10 + '"'
compare {
  _delete! { str.dup.delete!('"') }
  _gsub!   { str.dup.gsub!('"', '') }
  _tr!     { str.dup.tr!('"', '') }
}

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _delete! is faster than _tr! by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> _tr! is faster than _gsub! by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
```

The string has to be `dup`ed otherwise the first operation against it will change the original string, skewing the results.

Comment: Could you add `delete!`, etc.?

Comment: `delete!` will be very similar to `delete` but because it returns different information and mutates the receiver it's not quite the same test. I will add a comparison with the `!` versions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional test. I thought the `!` versions might be considerably faster, but as you report, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to achieve via the detection of quotes is to remove them afterwards, just remove them wholesale to begin with.

```
"\"which one is your favorite\"".gsub /"/, ''
```

Comment: If they exist, I want to remove them and follow different logic. If they don't exist, I follow a different logic. Hence I won't be able to use the way you have it. The check for quotes existence needs to be a completely independent step